# Dojo aspect not working for ready

Tags: dojo

I want to have an aspect which does some task after dojo ready is called. The code is given below,

```
aspect.after(dojo, "ready", function(deferred) {
    loader.hide();
});
```

The loader.hide() is not called after the page ready function is called. But the above code is working good with xhr instead of ready. Will aspects work for dojo/ready ? Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance for your help

===============================================

After few trial and errors, got this working by using

```
dojo.ready(function() {
});
```

Wanted to know why the aspect is not working with

```
 require(["dojo/ready"], function(ready) {
        ready(function() {
        });  
 });
```

Comment: After few trial and errors, got this working by using dojo.ready(function() {

Comment: I think the second approach is more understandable. I'm not sure an aspect is the best approach in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try using dojo/domReady too. You are **not** allowed to map domReady to any variable, so that is why it has to appear at the end:

```
require(["dojo/ready","dojo/domReady!"],function(ready) {
    ready(function()  {
     // Your code
    });

});
```